# Avoiding a divide by zero error in a case statement

Tags: sql

I am getting a divide by zero error in my script.
Can anyone please help.

I am trying to divide two records and one of them has zero in it. I dont want to lose the row, please advise.

```
select DATEPART(Year,Request_date) as "Year",
       DATEPART(Month,Request_date) as "Month",
       COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION]) as "Request" ,
       sum(case when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as "Paid in 24hrs",   
       COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION])/sum(case when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as "Achieved"
FROM suspension_br
  where REQUEST_STATUS = 'OTHERS'
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year,Request_date),DATEPART(Month,Request_date)
```

Comment: "I dont want to lose the row" - so what value do you *want* to have returned if a division by 0 is the current alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a second `case` to check the result of the `sum`:

```
case
when sum(case when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
then COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION])/sum(case when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
else 0 /* a default value that makes sense to you */
end as "Achieved"
```

Comment: @Nugeswale: Need more help? If not, since you are new, please don't forget to mark your question answered by checking the check mark before the answer you liked most.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I could assume you are using MSSQL and therefore you could use `nullif` which returns `null` if two arguments are equal. So for example your code could look like :

```
COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION])/nullif(sum(case when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end),0) as "Achieved"
```

What it does is if the value of the `sum` operator is equal `0` then the divisor is turn from  zero into  `null` and that will result in the entire equation to become `null`.

Answer (score 0):

use another case statement to check the result of your sum

```
select DATEPART(Year,Request_date) as "Year",
       DATEPART(Month,Request_date) as "Month",
       COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION]) as "Request" ,
       sum(case 
             when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 
             else 0 
           end) as "Paid in 24hrs",   
       case 
         when sum(case 
                    when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 
                    else 0 
                  end) = 0 then 'whatever you want in this case' 
         else COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION])/sum(case 
                                                 when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1  
                                                 else 0 
                                               end) as "Achieved"
FROM suspension_br
  where REQUEST_STATUS = 'OTHERS'
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year,Request_date),DATEPART(Month,Request_date)
```

although this is pretty nasty looking, so you could tidy it up a bit with a sub-select:

```
select 
  year, 
  month, 
  request, 
  PaidIn24hrs, 
  case
    when PaidIn24hrs = 0 then 'whatever you want in this case'
    else request/PaidIn24hrs
  end as "Achieved"
from 
(
    select DATEPART(Year,Request_date) as "Year",
           DATEPART(Month,Request_date) as "Month",
           COUNT([MONTH_OF_SUSPENSION]) as "Request" ,
           sum(case 
                 when [PAYMENT_<=24HRS] = 'Y' then 1 
                 else 0 
               end) as "PaidIn24hrs"
    FROM suspension_br
      where REQUEST_STATUS = 'OTHERS'
    GROUP BY DATEPART(Year,Request_date),DATEPART(Month,Request_date)
)
```